# How to implement triggers in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, triggers

I want to implement something similar to triggers in hibernate.

What I need is when a column in a table attains a specific value, a row should be inserted in another table or some other table should be updated.

How do I implement this in hibernate ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's described in [Chapter 14. Interceptors and events](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#events).

You can, for example, intercept a post-update event.

However, using the event system for *business* operations might not be the best idea (they are best used for infrastructure concerns). You should use a higher level layer for that.

Comment: hey could you please elaborate why using event system in this case might not be a good idea.. is there a problem which i am not seeing ??

Comment: @Juzer it's just considered good practice. Your data layer should be simple and dumb, while your service layer should do most of the work. And creating new data in response to an event is something that belongs in the service layer, not the data layer (even though it's probably easier to achieve in the data layer).

Comment: What about time stamps like [I'm asking here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544951/propagate-last-updated-time-stamp-from-sub-tables-to-main-table)? Would one use the event system or interceptors?

Comment: Is there one way to intercept or listen to list of saveAll(List..) method?

Comment: @JonathanJohx I recommend asking that as a separate question. This is an 8 year-old answer and I haven't used NHibernate for over 5 years.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon It's OK, thank you! I hope you can answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53824506/how-to-implement-triggers-to-intercept-a-collection-in-hibernate  , thanks a lot in advance.