# Hibernate mapping in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables;

*Street* has

```
 "Street_id", "StreetName", "description"
```

and *Path* has

```
 "path_id", "pathDescription", "path_name"
```

and there is one table more,

*Street-path* has

```
  "path_id", "Street_id"
```

Now I want to create a relationship between these tables such that when ever record is deleted from *Street*, record from *Street-path* will also be deleted, but they can't have direct relation ship. Only *Street* and *Path* can have direct relationship, and record in *Path* should keep intact.

How to do it in hibernate?

PS: I am using xml, not annotations for hibernate mapping.

Comment: Do you have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: I tried, and created direct relation ship but couldn't figure out how to do the exact thing that is mentioned that is why i asked here.

Comment: I think you should try this http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-many-to-many-1.html and get back with your code (mappings, access, etc) if it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Criteria api. You actually do not need any relationship, you just need street_id and you have it already. You can try this;

```
public void removeStreet(Street street) //this reference is an instance 
{                                       //of Street entity that you want to remove
   session.clear();
   session.delete(street);
   session.flush();

   StreetPath streetPath = new StreetPath(); //create new instance of StreetPath entity
   streetPath.setStreetId(street.getId());   //with id of deleted row of Street table  

   session.clear();
   session.delete(streetPath);
   session.flush();
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: how, if you could please give example?

Comment: @Sobia I tried to give an example. You must create a session first, I guess you have one already. BTW you don't need to use Path entity for this process.

Comment: this method that u mentioned i already know ... but I want to do exact what I posted in my query "when ever record is deleted from Street, record from Street-path will also be deleted 'automatically',and record in Path should keep intact" ... and to do so I will not need to query StreetPath seperatly.

Comment: @Sobia Maybe this link helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486413/how-to-imlement-triggers-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tutorial: [Hibernate mapping](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-many-to-many-xml-mapping-example/)

Comment: This is not really an answer.

Comment: For when ever record is deleted from Street, record from Street-path will also be deleted, you should use `cascade` attribute in XML

Comment: I have not tried, but everywhere in hibernate tutorial write this, you can try it and it `SQL` for your problem, use `cascade` too.

Comment: I do not need to try this actually, you advised using 1:m while the relationship is obviously m:n and then suggested something that you heard about somewhere..