# How can implement Triggers in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, triggers, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria

Two Tables Country And State
Both have name and id status columns
when insert state table update country column status 'YES'
On Hibernate

Like SQL Triggers on Hibernate

How can implement  Triggers in Hibernate ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement triggers in hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486413/how-to-implement-triggers-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JPA listeners for that, something like :

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(StateListener.class)
public class State {
}
```

and your StateListener class, with the annotation @PostPersist

```
public StateListener {
  @PostPersist
  public void process(State state) {
    // set the status here
  }
}
```

hibernate doc on this : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: Can you post country and state code ? Update your post and i'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one-many relation between Country-State right? You can in Country Entity impl a method like `addState(State state){this.status=true; this.states.add(state)}`

If you defined the cascading, saving `country` object will lead to the `state` object also get saved. And the `status` flag of `country` object was set to true.

You can also implement `removeState(State state)` there you check if the list (states) is empty after the removing, set the `status` flag to false.